# Symfony 4 Won't Login When Changing To Production Mode

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am having a strange issue, when i switch the environment to production on symfony 4 the login doesn't work, it gives me no error it simply reloads the login page. As soon as i switch it to dev again it works. Since there is no error i haven't a clue what is going on and wondered if anyone has figured out this issue before?

I also noticed that for some reason symfony never generates any log files in var/log - no dev logs or production logs, any idea on why this might be?

The login doesn't work on the admin side, the font end works but it's using a different method, the front is angular and makes ajax calls to the server to log in then uses JWT, but the admin is just basic symfony with a different user model and AdminAuthenticator.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\AdminUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

/**
 * Class AdminAuthenticator
 * @package App\Security
 */
class AdminAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{

    use TargetPathTrait;

    /**
     *
     */
    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'adminLogin';

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;
    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $urlGenerator;
    /**
     * @var CsrfTokenManagerInterface
     */
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;

    /**
     * AdminAuthenticator constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator
     * @param CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }


    /**
     * @return string|void
     */
    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed|void
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @return object
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $AdminUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(AdminUser::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$AdminUser) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $AdminUser;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $providerKey
     * @return Response|void|null
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

       return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('adminMembersListing'));

    }

    /**
     * @param $credentials
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
{
    return $credentials['password'];
}
```

}

Here is the security config:

```
security:

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    chain_provider:
      chain:
        providers: [app_user_username,app_user_email]
    app_user_username:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: username
    app_user_email:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
    adminusers:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\AdminUser
        property: username


  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    admin:
      anonymous: ~
      provider: adminusers
      pattern: ^/admin/
      form_login:
        check_path: /admin/login
        login_path: /admin/login
        default_target_path: adminDashboard
      logout:
        path: /admin/logout
        target: /admin/login
    main:
      anonymous: ~
      provider: chain_provider
      user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
      json_login:
        check_path: /user/login
      logout:
        path: /user/logout
        target: /
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator



      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
  encoders:
    App\Entity\AdminUser:
      algorithm: bcrypt
      cost: 15

    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt
      cost: 15
```

It's making no sense why it works fine in dev mode but not production.

Comment: did you get errors executing `bin/console clear:cache --env=prod` ?

Comment: @Manzolo no errors clearing cache no

Comment: You need to add a custom configuration to Monolog so you can catch all errors you're interested in. You can temporally copy the config from the dev file and put it on the prod one. See the doc for more: https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#monolog if for some reason the logs aren't generated you need to check dir permissions.

Comment: @WilliamsA. the logs never create, no matter what symfony project i do or in dev or prod, never any logs. The folder permissions are 775 so it should work

Comment: @MMMWeirdo Maybe you have something wrong with your environment, this kind of issues tend to appear in docker containers. Are you using docker for this project?

Comment: @WilliamsA. nope no docker

Comment: @MMMWeirdo Then you have to make sure the log folder exists and try to clear the cache with the bin/console to see if it throws any specific error.